# How to apply patch probably created with diff -r command?

Tags: linux, diff, patch

Until now I created patches on Linux with this:

```
diff -rupN oldDir newDir > fix.patch
```

and applied them with this (from the oldDir):

```
patch -p1 < fix.patch
```

Now, I need to do a patch somebody else created and when I try this method, I get:

```
patch: **** Only garbage was found in the patch input.
```

I am not sure how this patch is generated (it has .diff extension). Partial content of patch file is: (just changed some file/folder names)

```
Only in ../oldDir: someFile1.a
diff -r ../oldDir/someFolder1/SomeFile3 ./someFolder1/SomeFile3
10c10
< #someContent1 
---
> #someContent1
Only in ../oldDir/someFolder1/someFolder2: someFile2.a
diff -r ../wfd_oldDir/someFolder1/someFolder2/someFile3 ./someFolder1/someFolder2/someFile3
2c2
< ##### Change the following for your environment: 
---
> ##### Change the following for your environment:
15,16c15,16
< LIBRARY_LINK =        ar cr 
< LIBRARY_LINK_OPTS =   
---
> LIBRARY_LINK =        ar cr
> LIBRARY_LINK_OPTS =
36c36
<   $(C_COMPILER) -c $(C_FLAGS) $<       
---
>   $(C_COMPILER) -c $(C_FLAGS) $<
```

....... (continue) .......

How can I apply this patch?

Answer (score 3):

Check for unix/windows line endings

Comment: ... line endings, or other character encoding issues. E.g., a patch coded in UTF-16 won't work.

Comment: I will check this, but I tried to make a test patch using "diff -r oldDir newDir" (in Linux) and I still get this message.

Is it possible to apply patch created like this?

Comment: up vote: you are right there are windows newline characters, but the patch is doing this among other stuff: it removes windows new lines... Any suggestion?

Comment: Try removing the windows new lines from the patch and see if it works